# Creating a subarray based based on substring matching

Tags: ruby

If I have an array of Strings, how can I create a sub-array that contains only elements from the original array that contains the substring "yellow"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`#grep`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) method for this:-

```
# will give all strings have a sub-string `yellow` as a subarry
array.grep(/yellow/)
```